# How to Pixel Reduction By Attribute "0" in Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want, if item which has class `.card-product-new-tag` has attribute `show-value` is equal to `0` and at the same time if item which has class `.card-product-sale-tag` has attribute `show-value` is equal to `1` then change css of item which has class `.card-product-sale-tag` from `top: -35px` to `top: 10px`.

So, shortly, I want to see red tag at the top, like yellow tag, if there is no yellow tag.

HTML:

```
<div class="card-product">
    <img class="card-product-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x1440">
    <img class="card-product-img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1201x1441">
    <div class="card-tag card-product-new-tag" show-value="1">YENİ</div>
    <div class="card-tag card-product-sale-tag" show-value="0">İNDİRİM</div>
</div>
<div class="card-product">
     <img class="card-product-img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x1440">
     <img class="card-product-img2" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1201x1441">
     <div class="card-tag card-product-new-tag" show-value="0">YENİ</div>
     <div class="card-tag card-product-sale-tag" show-value="1">İNDİRİM</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card-product-new-tag {
    top: 10px;
}

.card-product-sale-tag {
    top: 45px;
}
```

I tried this but it's not working:

```
if ($(".card-product-sale-tag").attr('show-value') == 1 && $(".card-product-new-tag").attr('show-value') == 0) {
    $(".card-product-sale-tag", this).css("top", "10px");//this is not the way I want by the way... I want "top: -35px" and finally "10px".
}
```

[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far to achieve above ? please add that as well in your question..

Comment: @Swati check out please.

Comment: what do you mean by `.. finally has top: 10px..` ? Also there are mutliple such divs ?

Comment: on what event did you insert this jquery code?